# How to call MetaTrader5 `initialize()` with login information?

Tags: python, api, forex, metatrader5

when I use initialize function without parameters the connection is established correctly. but when I add any parameter like the 'login' it is not working

```
account=#account_number
authorized=mt5.initialize()

if authorized:
    print("connected to account #{}".format(mt5.account_info()))
else:
    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))
```

using the above code will connect correctly

but when I edit it like that
 `authorized=mt5.initialize(login=account)`

it won't connect and give me this error and I am sure of my account number and all the other details
`failed to connect at account #53895161, error code: (-2, 'Terminal: Invalid params')`

Answer (score 0):

mt5.initialize() Establish a connection with the MetaTrader 5 terminal.

use mt5.login() for login:

```
authorized = mt5.login(1234, password = "password", server="server")
```

Answer (score 0):

Mt5 - Under the hood is C++, and requires the correct typed parameters. The login parameter is expecting an int, so if you're reading it as a string you'll need to type cast it.

```
# Notice the int typecast.
account = int(keyring.get_password("MyMT5","AccountId"))
password = keyring.get_password("MyMT5","Password")

if not mt5.initialize(login=account, password=password, server="MyServer" ):
    print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt5.last_error())
    quit()
```